# Python bs4: How to Repeat "For" Loop with a Different Expression List if a Certain Condition is Met?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a `for` loop where once it gets to the last `comment-index` attribute on page 1, it will repeat the loop but with the data of page 2.

```py
data_page_1 = '''<div>
 <div>
   <div comment-index="1">Page 1 Comment 1</div>
 </div>

 <div>
   <div comment-index="2">Page 1 Comment 2</div>
 </div>
'''

data_page_2 = '''<div>
 <div>
   <div comment-index="1">Page 2 Comment 1</div>
 </div>

 <div>
   <div comment-index="2">Page 2 Comment 2</div>
 </div>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data_page_1, 'lxml')

for comment in soup.find_all(attrs={"comment-index":True}):
    print(comment.text)
    if comment == soup.find_all(attrs={"comment-index":True})[-1]:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data_page_2, 'lxml')
```

However, the code above doesn't continue the loop with the data of page 2, although I entered a new value to the variable `soup` and it only prints:

```
Page 1 Comment 1
Page 1 Comment 2
```

Does anyone have any insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
data_pages = [data_page_1, data_page_2]

for page in data_pages:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

    for comment in soup.find_all(attrs={"comment-index":True}):
        print(comment.text)
```

Output:

```
Page 1 Comment 1
Page 1 Comment 2
Page 2 Comment 1
Page 2 Comment 2
```